# How can I make this necklace longer?

Tags: jewelry

(See related question [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/1949/30).)

I was given a necklace with a cute geode pendant. Love the color, but it doesn't fit me well -- I don't like the length it hangs at, and I don't like that the stone is horizontal instead of vertical.

It's a fairly thin silver chain, connected to a couple of loops which connect to embedded rings in the rock itself.

[image: close-up picture of pendant]

What can I do to make this longer? Do I need to replace the full chain (somehow) or can I extend what I've got?

Comment: How much work are you wanting to do or are comfortable doing? Making it hang vertically would (probably) be a good amount of work. Making it longer would be simple. Perhaps better as two questions?

Comment: I'm moderately comfortable with wire work and even have some (tiny) tools, and I love the stone enough that I'm happy to put in the effort and/or learn necessary skills. I split the second question out (should have known better!)

Answer (score 5):

If you want it to hang vertically you will need to do a fair amount of reworking of the setting, this is complicated by any soldering runs the risk of damaging the stone.

If you just want to extend the chain it is probably just as easy to buy a new chain of the correct length and do a direct swap. You can get a huge variety of chains from jewelers supplier or indeed ebay for not too much money, indeed just a waxed cotton or leather thong might be just as good with this piece.

If you want it mounted vertically you will need to cut off the existing rings and file them flat to the mount and then add a new ring at one of the narrow ends.

Here you have two practical options, first to get a blank silver mount of the right size and shape and glue the existing piece on with epoxy or you could wrap the whole thing with silver wire to create a sort of 'cage'.

Comment: Please address issues of vertical mounting on the linked question and save this answer to address only the issue of lengthening the chain.

Answer (score 3):

if you make long links you can extend the existing chain in a way that could be interpreted as "original design" .. by this I mean make two links that are the same flat rings as the chain has, but with a long rod in between .. rod to be of the length needed to extend the chain to the requisite length.

as for hanging it length-wise .. an interesting way to hang it with minimal mods to the existing piece .. close the existing chain using a ring at the end of a "long link" but rather than the other end of the long link's rod having another ring .. make the end of it a hook that goes around the top of the square bit with the gem stones in .. and silver solder it to the ring on the side.

to balance the piece so it hangs correctly adjust the length of the horizontal arm of the hook 
[image]
see that the vertical arm is off center? that is to balance the weight to the side attachment

Answer (score 2):

If you have some chain identical to the chain on your necklace, extending the chain is not too hard to do. Since the chain is made up of small metal rings, all you have to do is twist open one ring on the chain and link in the extra chain.